# Android alarmManager setRepeating not triggering

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to setup an alarm at a specified time, but it is not being caught in my reciver.

Setup:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActionReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (current.getTimeInMillis() + 60000),3600000, pendingIntent);
```

Here is my reciver:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); //breakpoint here that doesn't get triggered 
  }
 }
```

I have put these values in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<receiver android:name="com.project.ActionReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```

Not sure what is wrong... thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the receiver be `ActionReceiver`

Answer (score 4):

Finally got the receiver to fire! I added the following code to my manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.project.ActionReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.project.ActionSetter" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Found here with details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16119351/1174574

Comment: You need either `android:exported="true"` OR the `<intent-filter>`. Not both. You had neither, which is why it wasn't working. The `<receiver>` needs to be available to apps outside of your app (for example, the `AlarmManager`). to do that you can either set `android:exported="true"` OR add an `<intent-filter>`. If you add an `<intent-filter>`, the assumption is that the `<receiver>` must be exported, so the default value of `export` is set to `true` in the presence of an `<intent-filter>`.

Answer (score 2):

The name of receiver in your manifest should be class name, such as:

```
<receiver android:name="com.project.ActionReceiver">
```

BTW, set an action is a better practice.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActionReceiver.class);
intent.setAction("com.project.action.ALERM");
```

And in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.project.ActionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.project.action.ALERM"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks William.That works.Though AndroidManifest.xml warns that :`Exported receiver does not require permission`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `android:name` attribute of your `receiver` to the  fully qualified class name of your `ActionReceiver`. Something like:

```
<receiver android:name="com.project.ActionReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Changed. It still does not trigger receiver however.

Comment: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))